# Math.Net Numerics library Transpose doesn't Work

Tags: c#, matrix, math.net, mathnet-numerics

So I want to transpose a matrix that I defined with

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;
     var MatrixValues = new double[]{1,1,2,2,3,3}
     var M = Matrix<double>.Build; 
     var C = M.Dense(3,2,MatrixValues);  
     var TR = C.Transpose();
```

So the result I get is a very strange matrix which is not the transpose. I think this is because the matrix is defined as DenseColumnMajor, but How can I change it?

So I have a 3 by 2 matrix like:

```
1 1
2 2 
3 3
```

and my desired result is:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

Comment: Good question. If you'd like to improve the question, showing us the desired output would be a plus :)

Comment: I added the desired value @JeffBridgman

Answer (score 1):

Transpose works correctly in this case:

```
C:
DenseMatrix 3x2-Double
1  2
1  3
2  3

TR:
DenseMatrix 2x3-Double
1  1  2
2  3  3
```

As documented, the specific builder expects the array to be in column major order. There are quite a few ways to create matrices. If you cannot rearrange the array in column-major order, maybe another way works better for you. See [Creating Matrices and Vectors](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html#Creating-Matrices-and-Vectors).